# Why is this question about werewolfs closed?

Tags: discussion

https://mythology.stackexchange.com/q/1483/62

I'm not sure why the question is closed. It's no worse than many of the other "myth-id" questions. I personally think that many of these myth-id questions should be off-topic, for a variety of reasons. But I don't think it's fair to close one myth-id question and leave the rest open.

So, why is this question closed? And why hasn't it been reopened?

This question is currently at -2. But downvotes don't mean that a question should be closed; just that a question is poorly researched, unclear, etc.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm not sure why the question is closed. It's no worse than many of the other "myth-id" questions.

Sure.

The current version of the question isn't stellar, but I think it's specific enough to not warrant a "too broad" closure any more.

However,  I think I should point out that [this](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/revisions/1483/2) is how the question looked when it was closed. That version was casting a very wide net, and that rarely works well on a Q&A site.

> I personally think that many of these myth-id questions should be off-topic, for a variety of reasons.

Then vote to close them.

Comment: Hi Yannis. Thanks for reopening the question. I saw the original revision of the question, and I agree with you that the question originally deserved to be closed. The reason why I made this meta post was that after the question was revised, it wasn't reopened. This was even though moderators had been notified in the comments, and even though the question had been flagged. My feedback about this would be for the moderation team to do a better job reopening questions after they've been improved. But yeah, I agree that the question originally deserved to be closed.

Comment: Re-opening questions is not a priority @Hamlet, and ideally it's something that shouldn't require moderator intervention.

Comment: *Re-opening questions is not a priority* that's completely bizarre. Why on earth would anyone want to edit their questions to fix their mistakes then? It's not like this site is flooded with activity, I'm sure you have time to reopen questions. *ideally it's something that shouldn't require moderator intervention* I can say the same thing about *closing* questions. This question was singlehandedly closed by one moderator; shouldn't a moderator be the one to reopen the question? This site doesn't support enough activity for people to reopen questions on their own.

Comment: Not a priority _for moderators_ @Hamlet. I thought that was clear from context. And no, I see absolutely no reason why a moderator should rush  in and re-open a question just because another (or the same) moderator closed it.

Comment: I never said "rushed", but after two comments and two flags it would be nice to get a response. I'm really not sure what kind of a point you are trying to make here: you closed the question, someone improved the question to address your complaints: it's only fair that the question gets reopened. To put it another way: if the community closed a question and the question was then improved, I would still want a moderator to reopen said question if the community wasn't able to get five votes together. It's not there are thousands of questions a day that moderators have to deal with.

Comment: @Hamlet And the question was re-opened. No idea what all this is about...